# How to specify in windows batch file to open spyder, change the working directory and run a script?

Tags: batch-file, spyder

I have created a windows batch file to run a code which is located in a particular folder. However, I am running the batch file but it does not work. What I want it to do is:

1. Change working directory in Spyder (Spyder is already openned so I don't want it to open it first)
2. Run the script I want to execute

Basically, the script I am running is plotting a bunch of graphs and all the files needed to create this are located in the working directory.

```
@echo off
"C:\Users\Mason\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\spyder.exe"
chdir /D "F:\optimisation"
"F:\optimisation\plot.py"
pause
```

The batch file runs fine without any errors, but nothing happens in Spyder e.g. it doesn't change the working directory and neither executes the code.

Comment: `start "" /WAIT "F:\optimisation\plot.py"`?

Comment: That didn't work either. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: `python.exe "F:\optimization\plot.py"` (given that the container of `python.exe` is specified in the `%PATH%` variable; if not, specify its full path, preferably quoted)?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "container of python.exe is specified in %PATH%"? By the way I am using a portable version of spyder. Would this be the issue?

Comment: The container is the directory that holds the executable. For `%PATH%` see [this](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html). Sorry, I don't know how to deal with `spyder`...

Comment: The problem is that it is able to locate spyder.exe and execute it but once opened it doesn't change thw working directory in spyder or run the plot.py script.

Comment: Spyder does not get the commands from the batch file. They belong to the batch file. They do not execute until spyder has already been run, and do not get passed on to spyder. If spyder accepts command line parameters, you can `cd` first, then run spyder and pass it the python script on its command line. If that's not possible, you're out of luck unless spyder will accept a text file as input.

Comment: To run Your Program : `cmd /c ""spyder.exe F:\optimisation\plot.py" "`

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
@echo off
setlocal
chdir /D "F:\optimisation"
"C:\Users\Mason\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.6.4\spyder.exe" "F:\optimisation\plot.py"
pause
```

That is, switch to the required directory, having set a local environment (this restores the original environment when the batch terminates).

Then run the `spyder` executable, providing it with the name of the  file. It would be normal practice to use this structure to provide a significant filename to an executable (eg `notepad fred,txt`)

Since the current directory when `spyder` runs is `f:\optimisation`, it is probably not necessary to specify the entire path in `spyder`'s argument.

Note this is all just speculation using normal practice. I have no experience of `spyder`- in fact, this is the first I've heard of it.